# How can I maintain camera stability without a tripod?

Tags: technique, night, shooting-technique, camera-shake, hand-held

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I hold my camera steady?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14962/how-can-i-hold-my-camera-steady)

I was shooting some photos last night and I was having trouble not blurring the images. The issue I know comes from me shaking while the shutter is open. A tripod would have been the perfect fix but I did not have a tripod on me at the time.

Are there any techniques, tips, or tricks that I can try to help maintain stability when shooting in low-light conditions without a tripod?

(This question applies to both point-and-shoot and DSLR cameras.)

Comment: It may be worth having a look at this question as well http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14962/how-can-i-hold-my-camera-steady